# How do I lock a carousel in Sencha Touch

Tags: scroll, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, carousel

I am using a carousel and would like to lock the carousel until a button is clicked.  Is there an easy way to do this?  Thanks!

My code so far:

```
Ext.define('BabyBen.view.MainCarousel', {
    extend: 'Ext.carousel.Carousel',
    xtype: 'maincarousel',

    config: {
        fullscreen: true,

        activeItem: 1,
        indicator: false,

        scrollable: {
            direction: 'vertical',
            directionLock: true
        },

        items: [{
            xtype: 'whatscreen'
        }, {
            xtype: 'startscreen'
        }, {
            xtype: 'whenscreen'
        }]
    }
});
```

Comment: what does your code look like?

Comment: @cclerville I have this so far:                       Ext.define('MyApp.view.MainCarousel', {
    extend: 'Ext.carousel.Carousel',
    xtype: 'maincarousel',
    
    config: {
        fullscreen: true,

        activeItem: 1,
        indicator: false,

        scrollable: {<br/>
            direction: 'vertical',
            directionLock: true
        },

        items: [{
            xtype: 'whatscreen'
        }, {
            xtype: 'startscreen'
        }, {
            xtype: 'whenscreen'
        }]
    }
});

Comment: Can you place it in your question. Its easier to read.

Comment: @cclerville I put it into the question for you!  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write a custom view for lockable carousel:

```
Ext.define("myApp.view.LockableCarousel",{
    extend: 'Ext.Carousel',
    initialize: function () {
        this.onDragOrig = this.onDrag;
        this.onDrag = function (e) { if(!this.locked){this.onDragOrig(e);} }
            },
    locked: false,
    lock: function () { this.locked = true; },
    unlock: function () { this.locked = false; }
});
```

Then you can extend this custom carousel anywhere using `extend` as well as you need to apply custom `lock` and `unlock` function for your desired lockable carousel through button handler:

```
Ext.define("myApp.view.CustomCarousel",{
    xtype: 'CustomCarousel',
    extend: 'myApp.view.LockableCarousel',

    config: {
        id: 'LockableCarousel',
        title: 'Example4',
        iconCls: 'cloud',
        indicator: false,        

        items: [

            {
                html : 'Item 1',
                style: 'background-color: #5E99CC'
            },

            {
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype : 'button',
                        text: 'Lock',
                        handler:function() {
                            Ext.getCmp('LockableCarousel').lock();
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        xtype : 'button',
                        text: 'Unlock',
                        handler:function() {
                            Ext.getCmp('LockableCarousel').unlock();
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }



        ]
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#bZnZi)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much!  I was able to get the carousel locked.  I appreciate your time.